# What is the best practice to use Constants in Laravel that leverage syntax checking in VS Code?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, constants

I am aware there are already a lot of answers being posted on best practices of using Constants in Laravel. I come from the Java world whereby constants are checked for validity in the editor.
In Laravel, using the config/constants.php method,

```
return [
    'options' => [
        'balance_outstanding' => 0,
        'balance_balance' => 1,
        'balance_partial_balance' => 2,
    ] 
];
```

Whereby we refer to the constant using Config::get('constants.options.balance_outstanding')) syntax, I cannot seem to trigger the syntax check nor autocomplete. It would be great if we can mouse over and see what the constant real value is. I am using
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client

So, my question is, what is the best way to define constants in such a way that the editor is smart enough to be aware that its a constant?

The method should also work on Laravel Blade Templates.

I believe the const within the class is so far the best option.

Comment: These aren't constants, they're static arrays. If you want the editor to validate the name and show you the value in real time while you're editing, then use actual constants.

Comment: the config values can still be changed, they are not constants and no way the editor knows the current value.

Comment: I am assuming that using something like this:
const CONSTANT = 'constant value';

Define it inside the class, and use it like class::CONSTANT in Laravel Blade views?

Answer (score 0):

A constant name starts with a letter or underscores, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. If you have defined a constant, it can never be changed or undefined.